# Split String Column on the Dataset<Row> with comma and get new Dataset<Row>

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on Spark SQL with Spark(2.0) and using Java API for reading CSV.

In CSV file there is a double quotes, comma separated Column. Ex: `"Express Air,Delivery Truck"`

Code for reading CSV and returning Dataset:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("header", "true")
                .load(filename)
```

Result:

```
+-----+--------------+--------------------------+
|Year |       State  |                Ship Mode |...
+-----+--------------+--------------------------+
|2012 |New York      |Express Air,Delivery Truck|...
|2013 |Nevada        |Delivery Truck            |...
|2013 |North Carolina|Regular Air,Delivery Truck|...
+-----+--------------+--------------------------+
```

But, I want to split `Shop Mode` to `Mode1` and `Mode2` Column and return as a Dataset.

```
+-----+--------------+--------------+---------------+
|Year |       State  |     Mode1    |         Mode2 |...
+-----+--------------+--------------+---------------+
|2012 |New York      |Express Air   |Delivery Truck |...
|2013 |Nevada        |Delivery Truck|null           |...
|2013 |North Carolina|Regular Air   |Delivery Truck |...
+-----+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Is there any way I can do this using Java Spark?

I tried with MapFunction, but call() method not returning Row. 
`Ship Mode` will be Dynamic i.e, CSV may contain one Ship Mode or two.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **selectExpr**, a variant of select that accepts **SQL expressions**, like this:

```
df.selectExpr("Year","State","split(Ship Mode, ',')[0] as Mode1","split(Ship Mode, ',')[1] as Mode2");
```

The result is a Dataset of Row.

Comment: Can you suggest another solution, when the number of comma separated values is unknown? it may vary from col1, col2,.... to col40. That is maxed at 40.

Answer (score 2):

We could:

- define a User Defined Function (UDF) to do the split operation only once
- use the select expression to map the splitted column into two new columns

eg.:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, Row}

val splitter = udf((str: String) => {
  val splitted = str.split(",").lift
  Array(splitted(0), splitted(1))
})

val dfShipMode = df.select($"year",$"state", splitter($"shipMode") as "modes")
                   .select($"year", $"state", $"modes"(0) as "mode1", $"modes"(1) as "mode2")
```